# UITableViewCell cell view design

Tags: swift

**how to get this view help pls**
I could not find most sources despite searching. Is there any way he can help me with this?
and i want this view =  https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQ0mg.png

i try this

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomCell") as! CustomTableViewCell
    cell.nameLabel.text = JsonAlbum[indexPath.row].title
    cell.backgroundColor = cellColorForIndex(indexPath: indexPath as NSIndexPath)
    return cell
}
 func cellColorForIndex(indexPath:NSIndexPath) -> UIColor{


        let row = CGFloat(indexPath.row)
        let section = CGFloat(indexPath.section)
        let saturation  = 1.0 - row / CGFloat(self.JsonAlbum.count)
        let hue =  section / CGFloat(self.JsonAlbum.count)

        return UIColor(hue: hue, saturation: saturation, brightness: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
    }
```

this code color :https://i.stack.imgur.com/wX5UJ.png

Comment: There should be no help given to those who don't help themselves but to ask for links or code.  At least, spell every word in your title correctly.

Comment: I worked for hours but I could not find this view. And im starter if u want see my codes i can share u....

Comment: @ElTomato You don't have to act all snobby to someone who is just getting started with this website and coding. They obviously don't really know how the rules work and we can help them learn. yusufdemirkoparan, can you please be more specific? Edit your question with more details, make your title clearer, and also add code/options you have tried. Do these three things first, and you will get better help.

Comment: I hope it changed as you wish

Comment: Your code looks pretty good (assuming the color calculation is right). What goes wrong with it?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQ0mg.png i want this

Comment: What does it look like currently? What is the issue?

Comment: @yusufdemirkoparan you have shown what you want but not what you are getting.  Have you tried changing the background colour of the cells content view as well?  e.g. `cell.contentView.backgroundColour = cellColorForIndex(indexPath: indexPath as NSIndexPath)`

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wX5UJ.png this code give me this view. @matt bro i want  https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQ0mg.png this view

Comment: Note that from red to yellow through orange, you can do this: Red to 1, blue to 0, the more there is green the more it's to "near" yellow `let allCells: CGFloat = totalNumberOfCells; let currentIndex: CGFloat = calculateTheCurrentIndexOfCellTrhoughtThePreviousSectionsAndRow return UIColor(red: 1, green: 1 - (currentIndex/totalNumberOfCells), blue: 0, alpha: 1)` But the more you have cells, the more you'll see gradient it "too light".

Comment: Great! Thank you @Larme